# Symmetricity and orthogonality

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

Can a 3 or more dimensional orthogonal matrix be symmetric ?

I am learning linear algebra and I couldn't seem to figure it out. I understand an Identity matrix or any column matrix with either 1 or -1 will be a solution but is there any other solution.

Comment: Identity matrix is symmetric and orthogonal.

Comment: The identity matrix is orthogonal and symmetric.

Comment: This one $$\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks! Is there any other solution expect for an identity matrix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a [Householder transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation): $P= I - 2 v v^T$ where $v$ is a unit vector.